# Missing data while loading data through ETL datastage

Tags: sql, db2, etl, netezza, datastage

I am trying to load data from DB2 table to Netezza through ETL Datastage. This is a delta load against a timestamp column.
So source SQL is like

```
select * from db2_table where timestamp_column > '2017-02-10 08:24:00';
```

After loading data in Netezza table, when I ran below query and got following result.

```
select max(timestamp_column) from netezza_table;
```

returns `'2017-02-10 11:17:56'`

Which looks good to me.

But I have noticed that we have a record in the DB2  table whose timestamp_column is `'2017-02-10 11:17:54'`, though that data is missing in destination Netezza table.

This is not a regular issue, but when the issue occurred, I have noticed that missing record's `timestamp_column` value is less than 1 or 2 second.

My question is, if `max(timestamp_column)` value is `'2017-02-10 11:17:56'` in Netezza then the ETL job should have fetched the `'2017-02-10 11:17:54'` record.

How it is possible to miss this record?

Comment: Any reason you have removed formatting that I added? Your question is quite hard to read without it.

Comment: Hey, I apologize. it happened by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible that the transaction that updated the `'2017-02-10 11:17:54'` record committed after the row had been read by the ETL job. The default isolation level in the DB2 database (I'm assuming DB2 for LUW) is CS, which only locks the current row when processing a cursor, and other transactions are free to update rows that have already been read.

You can try increasing the ETL job's isolation level to RR to ensure the result set does not change until you're done reading it, but keep in mind that it will affect concurrency of updates on the DB2 side.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Isolation level in my ETL job is RU. As source table is a transaction table and multiple records insert per second. So what is the best way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Well, that depends on what's more important to you: consistency or concurrency. If you absolutely need a consistent snapshot of the source table, you'll have to prevent updates, killing concurrency. If you cannot sacrifice concurrency, you'll have to live with slightly inconsistent data until the next ETL run.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is next time ETL will fetch data from source table where timestamp_column > '2017-02-10 11:17:56'
(as we are loading delta records through this job).
so those missing data will not be available in my destination table.

Comment: Then you'll have to rethink your approach. There's no free lunch.

Comment: Update: I  have updated one record in DB2 table without commit. So..  Case 1: Isolation Level is "Read uncommitted" and  SQL query is `select * from table_name where id=123;` And I am getting old value (not updated value). 

Case 2:  Isolation Level is "Read uncommitted" and  SQL query is `select * from table_name where id=123 WITH UR;` and this time I am getting updated record.  My question is why I am not getting updated value from Case 1 as "Read uncommitted"  is defined as isolation level in DB2 connector stage.

Comment: SQL statement processing is not atomic. T1 fetches row R1. T1 fetches R2. T2 updates R1. T1 never knows R1 was updated _after_ it had read it.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve your problem could be a row change timestamp.
This timestamp is generated by DB2 automaically at insert or update time and therefore a perfect solution to determine deltas.
Add a additional column to your source table like this

```
rct timestamp not null generated always for each row on update as row change timestamp
```

To avoid conflicts because of the DDL change you could also defined this column as "hidden". This means it can be explicitly selected but is not returned when running a

```
SELECT * FROM tab
```